# Session from iframe to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, iframe

How come when I create a session from an iframe within a domain and then try access the session from another iframe it works fine but when I try access the session through ajax it does not work?

---

## Example:

#### Website (iframe.php):

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['session'])){
    $_SESSION['session'] = $_POST['session'];
    echo "created session";
}else if(isset($_GET['want'])){
    //for ajax request
    die($_SESSION['session']);
}
?>
<form action="iframe.php" method="post">
SESSION VAL:<input name="session" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['session']?>" type="text"/><br>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

#### HTML

```
<iframe src="iframe.php">

</iframe>
<br>SESSION FROM AJAX:
<div id="AJAX"></div>
```

#### AJAX

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $.get( "iframe.php?want", function( data ) {
        $( "#AJAX" ).html( data );
    });
},1000);
```

#### [See Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7ed3efr/)

Comment: Try starting the session before outputting headers.

Comment: @Matt No difference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up about how to do CORS. Shortly, to make browser send session with ajax you have to add some fields to your xhr:

```
$.ajax({
  url : "https://crypter.co.uk/iframe.php?want",
  xhrFields : {
    withCredentials : true // <-- this
  },
  success : function( data ) {
    $( "#AJAX" ).html( data );
  }
});
```

And you'd have to allow such request serverside, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/2805519).

Comment: @Maximilian what do you mean?

Comment: Well I created a session at Iframe.php when accessing it with Ajax and then on success created an Iframe with the domain but there is no session.

Comment: @Maximilian I'd ask you to make a fiddle